# Changing functional component state from other functional component

Tags: reactjs, state

I want to change state from other component. Please someone reply. My code is following. In the same code structure, I want to change state of second component by changing some values in first component.  Also I want to learn React Redux with simple component. Anyone interested in teaching me React Redux...

```
import "./App.css";
import React, { Component, useState } from "react";

function Component1(props) {
  const [value, setvalue] = useState("");

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setvalue(e.target.value);
  };
  return (
    <div style={{ background: "#f9f9f9" }}>
      <label>Component 1: </label>
      <input
        className={props.class}
        placeholder={props.placeholder}
        value={value}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

const Component2 = (props) => {
  const [value, setvalue] = useState("");
  return (
    <div style={{ background: "#f5f5f5", marginTop: "10px" }}>
      <label>Component 2: </label>
      <input
        class={props.class}
        placeholder={props.placeholder}
        value={value}
        onChange={(e) => setvalue(e.target.value)}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App" style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column" }}>
        <Component1 placeholder="Enter Some Value" class="sibling" />
        <Component2 placeholder="Updating Value" class="sibling" />
      </div>
    );
 }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You wanted to change the functional component to class component?

Comment: Functional component to functional component. 

Also Functional component to class component and class component to class component

Comment: You can always use react context api for this. And yes you will need some sort of contexting if you want to change state of one sibling from another sibling. Redux is also an option but can be avoided if your work in simple and small like this.

Comment: @PhoenixCreation, can you form these code?. I know contextApi is using for updating state from one to other component. But I don't know how to code?

Comment: Do you want to sync both components' input field? like if I change text in one component, it should change in second component?

Comment: @PhoenixCreation, yes absolutely. Also if you are interested, you can form code in new file how to change the same state using Redux.

Comment: For something simple with just two neighboring children components, then [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) is the tool/pattern you might want to implement. Don't reach for the [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) until you're lifting the state several levels and drilling the props through a bunch of intermediate components that don't care about the state that was lifted. Redux is pretty simple, but probably overkill for your trivial snippet example. What do you want to update from one component to the other?

Comment: @PhoenixCreation, thanks for your cooperation. You did well. But it's not fulfill my requirement. I changed the above code according to my exact requirement. Can you take a look above code and can you please tell how to change state in output?

Comment: Your recent edit is, IMHO, the perfect use-case for lifting state up. `UserNameInput` is essentially a fully controlled input, and `UserNameOutput` is just displaying that state. Move the `first`, `middle`, and `last` state into the parent `App` and pass down the props.

Comment: @AbdulRasheedAzar Please do _not_ change the question after it has been answered. Ask a follow-up question instead. I rolled back the changes.

Comment: @ModusTollens, Thanks. I am new to stack overflow. Checking how to ask a follow-up question.

Comment: @AbdulRasheedAzar No problem, welcome to Stack Overflow! To ask a follow-up question you should write a new one. If it is related to this one, it's best to add a link to this question with a quick summary.

Comment: @AbdulRasheedAzar I just noticed that you altered your question again... That's not good. It invalidates existing answers. Please don't do it.

Answer (score 0):

### with context api

```
import "./App.css";
import React, { Component, useState,createContext, useContext } from "react";

const InputContext = createContext()

function InputProvider(props) => {
  const [value, setvalue] = useState("");
  return (
    <InputContext.Provider value={{value,setvalue}}>
      {props.children}
    </InputContext.Provider>
  )
}

function Component1(props) {
  const {value, setvalue} = useContext(InputContext);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setvalue(e.target.value);
  };
  return (
    <div style={{ background: "#f9f9f9" }}>
      <label>Component 1: </label>
      <input
        className={props.class}
        placeholder={props.placeholder}
        value={value}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

const Component2 = (props) => {
  const {value, setvalue} = useContext(InputContext);
  return (
    <div style={{ background: "#f5f5f5", marginTop: "10px" }}>
      <label>Component 2: </label>
      <input
        class={props.class}
        placeholder={props.placeholder}
        value={value}
        onChange={(e) => setvalue(e.target.value)}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <InputProvider>
      <div className="App" style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column" }}>
        <Component1 placeholder="Enter Some Value" class="sibling" />
        <Component2 placeholder="Updating Value" class="sibling" />
      </div>
      </InputProvider>
    );
 }
}
```

Don't forget to wrap your app component with Provider Component, Only children components of Provider component will have access to this context.

Comment: So much of Thanks to you. Can you please share how to wrap?

Comment: It is already done in the code above. Check the first component in return of app component. `InputProvider` component is wrapped through entire `div className="app"` component. Let me know if this code works or not?

Comment: Code works. Thanks. Can you do the same by using Redux? please

Comment: I am sorry but I don't know redux that much. My all requirements gets satisfied with context api and it is more simple to learn too. Good to know that code works.

Comment: Thanks again. I have one clarification. Can we do all our requirement using context api instead of using Redux?. I am also tried to learn Redux for more complicative changing states. But I could not understand Redux.

Comment: Well actually yes. Both does the same thing and context api was actually introduced to solve the problems of redux like too much boilerplate code for simple tasks. Also context api is provided in react and redux is additional library. If you have very big project where you have so many states like hundreds and have to filter them on certains events and like that then redux is helpful. But at the end it based on your preference. Context API if you prefer simple and quick solutions and Redux for more high level options.

Comment: "context api was actually introduced to solve the problems of redux" isn't exactly true... redux is built on top of the React Context API. With the Context API alone you need to manage the state yourself, with Redux it handles the management, but you need to describe *how* you want to update state.

Comment: @PhoenixCreation, thanks in advance. You did well. But it's not meet my exact requirement. I have used reusable components. I have asked in follow-up question. Can you please please look at this and write code for me?

Comment: @PhoenixCreation I rolled back the question to its original form, no need to change your answer. Questions with answers should not be changed.

Answer (score 0):

With something as simple as two neighboring children then I would suggest using [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html). Basically the parent component has the "source of truth" state value, and child component 2 is allowed to keep a local copy of the lifted state that it can update. When the source of truth state in the parent updates however, child 2 receives the updated state.

```
function Component1(props) {
  return (
    <div style={{ background: "#f9f9f9" }}>
      <label>Component 1: </label>
      <input {...props} />
    </div>
  );
}

const Component2 = (props) => {
  // handle local state
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const changeHandler = (e) => setValue(e.target.value);

  useEffect(() => {
    // respond to lifted state updates
    setValue(props.value);
  }, [props.value]);
  
  return (
    <div style={{ background: "#f5f5f5", marginTop: "10px" }}>
      <label>Component 2: </label>
      <input {...props} value={value} onChange={changeHandler} />
    </div>
  );
};

function App() {
  // Common lifted state
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const changeHandler = (e) => setValue(e.target.value);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Component1
        placeholder="Enter Some Value"
        className="sibling"
        value={value}
        onChange={changeHandler}
      />
      <Component2
        placeholder="Updating Value"
        className="sibling"
        value={value}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit changing-functional-component-state-from-other-functional-component]

#### Redux Implementation

Since you've expressed an interest in learning Redux, here's a simple redux implementation.

state.slice.js

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const stateSlice = createSlice({
  name: "state",
  initialState: "",
  reducers: {
    updateValue: (state, action) => action.payload
  }
});

export const actions = {
  ...stateSlice.actions
};

export default stateSlice.reducer;
```

index.js

```
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import App from "./App";
import reducer from "./state.slice";

const store = configureStore({ reducer });

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

App.js

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { actions } from "./state.slice";

function Component1(props) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const value = useSelector((state) => state);

  return (
    <div style={{ background: "#f9f9f9" }}>
      <label>Component 1: </label>
      <input
        {...props}
        value={value}
        onChange={(e) => dispatch(actions.updateValue(e.target.value))}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

const Component2 = (props) => {
  const state = useSelector((state) => state);

  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  const changeHandler = (e) => setValue(e.target.value);

  useEffect(() => {
    setValue(state);
  }, [state]);

  return (
    <div style={{ background: "#f5f5f5", marginTop: "10px" }}>
      <label>Component 2: </label>
      <input {...props} value={value} onChange={changeHandler} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>

      <Component1 placeholder="Enter Some Value" className="sibling" />
      <Component2 placeholder="Updating Value" className="sibling" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit changing-functional-component-state-from-other-functional-component (forked)]

***Note:** You should note here that not much more code was added over the "lifting state up" pattern nor even the "Context API" solution. As I said, redux is already pretty simple, and redux-toolkit addresses the "boilerplatiness" complaints. Hopefully you see how simple it is to integrate redux into an app with this example.*

## Update

Update to address your follow-on question. I still believe lifting state up is the pattern you should apply. Declare a single state in the parent `App` component and define the change handler. Pass the state and handlers to the children components.

```
function UserNameInput(props) {
  return (
    <div style={{ background: "#f9f9f9" }}>
      <label>
        {props.label}
        <input
          name={props.name}
          className={props.class}
          placeholder={props.placeholder}
          value={props.value}
          onChange={props.onChange}
        />
      </label>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
function UserNameOutput(props) {
  return (
    <div style={{ background: "#f9f9f9" }}>
      <label>{props.label}</label>
      <h3>{props.value}</h3>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState({
    fname: "",
    mname: "",
    lname: ""
  });

  const changeHandler = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setValue((state) => ({
      ...state,
      [name]: value
    }));
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>

      <h2>Input</h2>
      <div className="App" style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column" }}>
        <UserNameInput
          placeholder="First Name"
          class="fname"
          name="fname"
          label="First Name"
          value={value.fname}
          onChange={changeHandler}
        />
        <UserNameInput
          placeholder="Middle Name"
          class="mname"
          name="mname"
          label="Middle Name"
          value={value.mname}
          onChange={changeHandler}
        />
        <UserNameInput
          placeholder="Last Name"
          class="lname"
          name="lname"
          label="Last Name"
          value={value.lname}
          onChange={changeHandler}
        />
      </div>
      <br />
      <h2>Output</h2>
      <div className="App" style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column" }}>
        <UserNameOutput label="First Name:" value={value.fname} />
        <UserNameOutput label="Middle Name:" value={value.mname} />
        <UserNameOutput label="Last Name:" value={value.lname} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit changing-functional-component-state-from-other-functional-component (forked)]

Comment: I appreciate you trying to help, but please don't encourage chameleon questions by altering answers when questions are changed. It's much better to rollback question changes and encourage proper follow-up questions. Thanks!

Comment: @ModusTollens I'm not altering my answer, I'm adding to it. OP seems to have edited their question and appended/issued a follow-up question, and I've appended to my answer. Perhaps you should be more direct with what you think is the correct course of action here. If you want OP to ask an *entirely* new question, then just come out and state that. Why shouldn't OP improve their question if it wasn't originally well formed?

Comment: I already added a comment on the question explaining how to ask a proper follow-up question. The correct course of action (esp. as someone who answered): rollback the question, explain why questions with existing answers shouldn't be changed, and explain how to ask a follow-up question.

Comment: @ModusTollens Ok, your comment finally explaining what you want came after my update. ‍♂️ IMO if OP's original question/issue is unresolved then the question should either be improved until a fitting answer arrives, or closed as "unanswerable".  Asking new questions just because you're not getting the answer you want is considered queue-jumping and is frowned upon. To be clear, I see your point and understand what you're saying, but I just disagree with you here on this one.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that's not true. The reason is that it invalidates answers. Other users who answered might not stick around to update their question, which could lead to downvotes. This problem was discussed several times on Meta. Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266768/1288408 as a starting point.

Comment: @ModusTollens Look, this isn't the place to have this discussion/debate, but I get it. I agree with you about follow-on questions... ***if the initial question has been sufficiently addressed***. It's unfortunate, but sometimes answers just become invalidated/outdated/irrelevant. If this is the hill you want to go and die on, then keep on fighting the good fight my friend.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep on cleaning up and informing people on how to improve Stack Overflow. I like that hill ;). Just thought I'd let you know to help avoid more work for curators in the future, that's all. Have a nice day!